# IBM MobileFirst 8 Invalid client signature

Tags: oauth-2.0, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I am using MobileFirst 8 to run my web  application. After creating a JAVA authentication adapter and a challenge handler, my application works fine on windows however I am facing the error below on Ubuntu :

```
[/mfp/api/registration/v1/self] failure. state: 403, response: undefined
Authorization request failed with response: "Invalid client signature."
```

I noticed that **com.mfp.oauth.application.data** and **com.mfp.oauth.clientid** are returned as null.

Any idea about this issue ?

Comment: Have you tried adding an exclusion rule to iptables?

Comment: @sk7, please respond.

Comment: No I didn't, but I uninstall MobileFirst 8 then I install it again  and everything seems ok now.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, upon reinstallation of the server component the exhibited error was no longer happening. I suspect a server restart or reset may have helped as well.

> No I didn't, but I uninstall MobileFirst 8 then I install it again and everything seems ok now.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is that ibm web sdk has a minimum server version requirements.
you solved this by removing and installing the server again. There are two other appropriate fixes for this:

1. Recommended way: update your mfpf server by installing the latest fixpack from [here](https://www-945.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/selectFixes?parent=ibm~Other%2Bsoftware&product=ibm/Other%20software/IBM%20MobileFirst%20Platform%20Foundation&release=8.0.0.0&platform=All&function=all&source=fc).

OR,

2. downgrade your sdk by running:

   ```
   npm install ibm-mfp-web-sdk@8.0.2016070716
   ```

   The above version fixed it for me but your MFPF server version might be different so you might need older packages. to see available versions:

   ```
   npm show ibm-mfp-web-sdk@* version
   ```